# mu4e overwrites minibuffer output when switching buffers

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area, mu4e

I'm using mu4e for email and I really like it.  The only time it annoys me is when I'm switching buffers and I want to see a list of suggested buffer names in the echo area / minibuffer, because mu4e insists on writing `[mu4e] Retrieving mail... /` into the echo area.  In order to refresh the list of buffer names I must edit the now invisible text in the minibuffer, but it only flashes for a moment as it is again overwritten by mu4e's notification.

I like this notification when I don't use the minibuffer, so I don't want to disable it completely.  Is there a way to prevent it from appearing when I'm actively using the minibuffer?

Comment: Here is an idea, which is one hundred percent *untested* -- find the section of code that is responsible for the `message` and add a condition -- `(if (minibufferp) [then insert the output in the *Messages* buffer and bypass the echo area] (message [email retrieval message]))`.  Here is what I use to insert text into the `*Messages*` buffer and bypass the echo area:  `(let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (with-current-buffer (messages-buffer) (goto-char (point-max)) (when (not (bolp)) (insert "\n")) (insert [email retrieval message]) (when (not (bolp)) (insert "\n"))))`

Comment: @lawlist: Don't use `minibufferp` for the test - use function `minibuffer-depth` or function `active-minibuffer-window`. It's not about whether the current buffer is a minibuffer; it's about whether the minibuffer is active.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for the suggestion -- I'll give it a try later on today using an example I am familiar with so I can see how it works in-house.

Comment: @lawlist Did you ever get a chance to work on this further?  I'm interested in solving the same problem.

Comment: I don't use `mu4e`, but I bet that a very small bounty would attract sufficient attention to find a good solution.  I haven't done any further work on the idea in the comment above -- it is something that I use daily when printing output from a running process with a filter directly to the `*Messages*` buffer so that I can go on about my business without muddying up the echo area -- the primary functions I do this with is compiling LaTeX .pdf files with `start-process` and running `rsync` with `start-process`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending code is right in `mu4e-update-mail-and-index`:

```lisp
    (unless mu4e-hide-index-messages
     (make-progress-reporter
      (mu4e-format "Retrieving mail...")))
```

which logs messages when the (undocumented) variable `mu4e-hide-index-messages` is nil. I prefer to disable it entirely, but to answer your question the following should do the trick:

```lisp
    (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
          (lambda () (setq mu4e-hide-index-messages t)))
    (add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
          (lambda () (setq mu4e-hide-index-messages nil)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this last snippet doesn't cover the case when switching to the minibuffer while retrieving mail.  I guess I'll just disable it with `mu4e-hide-index-messages`.  Thanks!